# Estimate the number of extreme points on random sequence on the plane.

Tags: probability, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Given a random 2-d sequence $X = (a_1, b_1), \cdots, (a_i, b_i), \cdots, (a_n, b_n)$ on the plane. $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. I can compute it's convex hull $CH(X)$ and count the extreme points(points on the boundary).

Suppose $X$ has such property $a_i \ge a_{i+1}$ and $b_i \leq b_{i+1}$. Both $a_i$ and $b_i$ are first generated independently, uniformly random from the same range, and then sorted in order

Now my question is, what's the expected number of extreme points with such a length $n$ sequence?

Here is a plot of sorted random $a$ and $b$:

[image]

Concatenate them form $X$ and extreme points of $CH(X)$:
[image]

Comment: How are the values of $X$ generated?

Comment: good point, both $a_i$ and $b_i$ are first generated independently, uniformly random from the same range, and then sorted in order

Comment: Can you supply a plot?

Comment: sure thing, just added two plots. hope that helps @user619894

Comment: Have you tried a induction/dynamic programming approach? If a point is an "upper extreme point" I think that adding new points means that the points before it cannot become extreme, and if adding a new point causes an extreme point to stop being extreme, then all extreme points after it also cease to be extereme.